# How can I reboot a Hyper-V guest after bluescreen?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012, bsod, reboot

We have a Server 2012 as Hyper-V host with several virtual machines. In one of these, a Windows 7 guest system crashed into a `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` bluescreen saying "Collecting error information" but staying at 0% for hours with maximum CPU load.

The "Power off virtual machine" menu item in the VM doesn't work, the status bar says "Shutting down..." but there is no progress. How can I reboot this VM?

Comment: I presume Hyper-V has a "power off VM" option?

Comment: My bad, I meant that the power off option didn't work anymore. I translated it the wrong way. Edited.

Comment: Is there a "force power off" option?

Comment: No, only "Shut down" and "Power off". Now we got the message "The virtual machine cannot change its state while it is in this state." (Microsoft!!?!?) I'll try to reboot the whole host, but that can't be a real solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way described here:

https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/528-killing-ending-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine-that-is-stuck

1. **Download** [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer)
2. **Find the GUID for your VM**
   Look in the Virtual Machines folder where your VM resides. There should be an XML file and a folder both labelled with the same **GUID**. Remember or write down at least the first couple and last few characters of the guid - you're going to need to match this.
3. **Find the GUID that's running**
   Run Process Explorer (you may need to right-click and Run As Administrator if you get Access Denied messages) and look for a bunch of VMWP.EXE files running. Open the properties on one, go to the Image tab, and look under Command Line. As a parameter on the command will be the GUID from the Virtual Machines folder. Keep looking until you find the one with the same GUID!
4. **Kill it!**
   After finding it, hit OK to the Properties window, then right-click on that VMWP.EXE and Kill Process! The Virtual Machine should immediately turn off.